# Run PHP file without opening it

Tags: php, sql, insert

Is it possible, to run my PHP code without opening it?

For example, I have "test.php" which includes the following SQL code:

```
`INSERT INTO Humans(Name) VALUES ('Ric')`
```

I want to run this code in every 30 seconds, but the problem is that I can't open it every 30 seconds. :)

Comment: Explain better why you cannot do this every 30s. It will help us help you.

Comment: It is useful if you mention if you run inder Windows, Linux, or another system. In linux you can use watch. http://linux.die.net/man/1/watch

Answer (score 0):

You can [schedule a task](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7) if you're using windows, or a cron job if you're on linux.

Answer (score 0):

For these cases, it is for the majority of web hosting solutions available CRON function (automatic call PHP scripts at a specified time).

The question is whether your web hosting provider allows calls PHP scripts in so short a time as 30 seconds as you say.

Answer (score 0):

Under Linux, cron tasks cannot run every 30 seconds as the cron granularity is only 1 minute.

If you want you can have a workaround by create a script that executes every minute but runs the command twice

**whatever.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /the/directory/where/the/script/is
php task.php
sleep 30s
php task.php
```

Make sure it's executable

`chmod +x whatever.sh`

Then setup cron to execute the script every minute

`* * * * * /path/to/whatever.sh`